# multiple unidirectional one-to-many relationship to the same class

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

```
public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private String phone;
}

public class Order {
    Collection<Contact> contacts;
}

public class Department {
    Collection<Contact> contacts;
}
```

I have these three classes and I'd like to create hibernate xml mapping files.
As it shows, I have multiple (unidirectional) one-to-many mappings in Order, and Department to the same class, Contact. How do I create mapping files for those three?

Comment: Can u post table structure here

Comment: See [Hibernate one-to-many](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#assoc-unidirectional-12m).  What problem are you facing?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Should I create multiple tables like OderContact and OrderDepartment? What if I have many more classes that have one-to-many relationship to Contact? Is this expected to create a relationship table fore each one?